# Accessing Heroku Postgres Instance from EC2

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2

I have an application that we are currently running on a number of co-located servers and I'm interested in moving everything to the cloud.

I have a legacy application running Postgres and its replacement application using MySql as its data store.  I'm interested in moving to EC2 and looking to do this as pain free as possible.  I was planning on using Amazon RDS for the MySql data store but am looking for options for the Postgres install.

I know that Heroku is built on top of EC2 and has Postres support and was wondering

Has anyone had any experience accessing a Heroku Postgres database from an application running in EC2.  Comments on Performance, Reliability ease of Administration

The other alternative is to install Postgres on EC2 with EBS volumes but I've heard mixed reviews on performance, reliablitity and ease of administration.

Thanks in advance, any experience and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this with several colocated boxes on the east coast. Heroku actually has a completely independent service: [Heroku Postgres](https://postgres.heroku.com/), which is built for this specific use case. The databases you create are all independent (not related to any Heroku apps).